# NoLongerAvailable Exception when trying google contacts API Sample

Tags: java, api, contacts

I'm trying to start with google calendar API. I started with this official link [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#audience) and downloaded the java sample code from here [Google API Samples](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list). I tried to run it and an Exception :

NoClassDefFoundError for .../util/NoLongerAvailableException
caused by
ClassNotFoundException : .../util/NoLongerAvailableException

can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when the JVM cannot find a class (and in your case `NoLongerAvailableException`). Make sure you have the relevant jar (`gdata-core-xx.yy.jar`) in your classpath or `WEB-INF/lib` folder that contains `NoLongerAvailableException`.

Comment: Yes gdata-core-1.0.jar is exists in myProject\gdata\java\lib

Comment: And there is an ant script to build it. In the google developers website also saw this run script line "ant -f gdata/java/build-samples.xml sample.contacts.run" but I couldn't understand. I dont have this "sample.contacts.run" . I built the script using the ant as usual

Comment: Set the library in your classpath and run your program.

Comment: It seems like I should run it using the ant command I wrote before. I did this and I can saw now some command line parameters sent and some data shows up. It is probably a project files structure issue ( I measn google samples may be organized in a form that I don't know about".

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by simply running the application using the ant script command given :

"ant -f build-samples.xml sample.xxxxx.run"

where xxxxxx is the example name (e.g. contacts or calendar) and You should run this command from inside the gdata/java folder.

You can also modify any of the code inside the java files of the example and re-run the script to check the updates.

Thank you all.